# Linked servers throw error using MSOLEDBSQL. "Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has stopped this transaction"

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, msdtc

To replicate:

Download and install [msoledbsql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
msiexec /i msoledbsql.msi ADDLOCAL=ALL IACCEPTMSOLEDBSQLLICENSETERMS=YES
```

Create localdb servers

```
SQLLocalDB create a
SQLLocalDB create b
```

In SSMS link servers using:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server = '(localdb)\a', @datasrc = '(localdb)\a', @provider = 'MSOLEDBSQL', @srvproduct = ''
```

Create a dummy db and table in linked server.

```
CREATE DATABASE a;
USE [a]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [id] [int] NULL
)
```

Attempt to query from the other

```
SELECT * FROM [(localdb)\a].a.[dbo].[TestTable]
```

Output

> Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has stopped this transaction.

Comment: `@datasrc` should be `a` which is the database name. You probably also want to setup a login mapping. Have you tried this with the SSMS wizard?

Comment: I'm encountering this same issue. Did you find a resolution?